# Abstract methods not compatible with interface methods

Tags: php, laravel, oop, repository, repository-pattern

Let's say I'm creating a repository pattern in Laravel and I have a UserRepositoryEloquent class. I also want a PostRepositoryEloquent class and they'll share a lot of methods (find, findAll, findOrFail etc). So I put those methods on an abstract BaseRepositoryEloquent class. Those methods would have previously returned UserInterface and PostInterface but now they'll all return the Laravel abstract Model class.

Each repository is also implementing their interface e.g. UserRepositoryEloquent and UserRepositoryFileStorage both implement UserRepositoryInterface which forces them both to implement their own 'find' method, however they wish, as long as they're both returning the type of UserInterface, but that's no longer the case now that UserRepositoryEloquent inherits those methods, which are returning Model; hence I now get the error:

`Declaration of UserRepositoryEloquent->find(id) must be compatible with UserRepositoryInterface->find(id)`

**UserRepository for File Storage**

```
<?php

class UserRepositoryFileStorage implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find(int $id): ?UserInterface
    {
        // fetch from file storage
    }
}
```

**UserRepository for DB Eloquent**

```
<?php

class UserRepositoryEloquent extends BaseRepositoryEloquent implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    // inherits 'find' from BaseRepositoryEloquent which returns type Model, not UserInterface
}
```

**Post Repository for Eloquent just for example**

```
<?php

class PostRepositoryEloquent extends BaseRepositoryEloquent implements PostRepositoryInterface
{
    // eloquent-post-specific methods
}
```

### Above 2 eloquent classes inherit Eloquent methods from base class

```
<?php

abstract class BaseRepositoryEloquent
{
    public function __construct(private Model $model) {}

    public function find(int $id): ?Model
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }
}
```

**Interface to force all user repositories to implement a 'find' method**

```
<?php

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find(int $id): UserInterface;
}
```

### User & Interface classes are what's returned

```
<?php

# Laravel Model Class
class User extends Model implements UserInterface
{
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->getAttribute('id');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

# Example just to show interface used for typehinting User entities
interface UserInterface
{
    public function getId(): int;
}
```

Tried thinking long and hard but haven't managed to think of a way around at this point other than removing typehints.

Comment: You could try doing something with generics, although these are currently only supported in DocBlocks, so might not quite be what you are looking for. Have a look here for more info: https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-by-examples

Comment: Given `public function find(int $id): ?Model` In PHP8.1 you can write `public function find(int $id): Model&UserInterface`. But in this case you can't use `?` (null) anymore. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pure-intersection-types

Comment: You need to show us what the error is, the exact error please

Comment: Sure, it's Declaration of UserRepositoryEloquent->find(id) must be compatible with UserRepositoryInterface->find(id). I've updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very easy, change `BaseRepositoryEloquent`:

```php
abstract class BaseRepositoryEloquent
{
    public function __construct(private Model $model) {}

    public function find(int $id): ?UserInterface
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }
}
```

And change UserRepositoryInterface:

```php
interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find(int $id): ?UserInterface;
}
```

Comment: You've restricted the BaseRepositoryEloquent class to only be able to return UnserInterface - it should be abstracted from any specific model so that other models' repository classes can use it e.g. if PostRepositoryEloquent extended BaseRepositoryEloquent it would have to return a type of user from its find method.

Comment: Then don't define anything here, just mark the method as abstract and let the child implement it...

Comment: We’ll that’s what I’m trying to avoid; I want the Model type hint there but it’s clashing so I’m trying to see if there’s a way around it and have both types or add some wrapper class or something like that

Comment: If you have different types (`UserRepository`, `PostRepository`) and they return different types, your `BaseRepository` cannot have a type defined that is not the interface the childs are going to use... I would advocate to NOT use repositories, it is sometimes an antipattern, specially with Eloquent. I personally create "Domain" classes, and I define what I want to do there. I need to register someone? I create a class called `User` and it has a `register` method, I do not care how you are looking for matches or whatever, do a normal query, no repositories, it will be 100% easier

Comment: Right, but Model is an abstract class in Laravel that both User and Post extend (given that they are models) and having a return type of Model on the BaseRepository means they can both adhere to that contract and I also get the Model autocomplete functionality in the IDE.

Comment: Then change `UserInterface` to `Model` if you always return a model. There is not much you can do

Comment:  then whats the point in the interface if everything that implements it is forced to return the same type? Thank you for your suggestions but all they amount to is exactly what I’m saying I want to avoid… better to just say “I don’t know then” or nothing at all ‍♂️

Comment: @MatCauthon I do know, I clearly do not fully undertstand what schema you want...  still, I recommend 100% NOT to use repository pattern, it is considered an anti pattern in Laravel, this is why it is so hard for you to make this work... use Domain classes (DDD), sorry for not being of help...